# Combinar correspondencia desde una macro en access

Tags: vba, ms-access, microsoft-office, ms-word

Buenos días dispongo de un access desde el cual mediante un botón ejecuto una macro. 
Dicha macro debe hacer 3 pasos:

-Vaciar el contenido de la tabla `T_AUX` (ya lo he conseguido)

-Ejecutar una consulta la cual volcará la información deseada en la tabla `T_AUX`

-Abrir un `.doc` el cual combinará correspondencia desde la tabla `T_AUX`,el fichero ya lo tengo y si ejecuto este último paso abriendo el fichero como doble clic va perfecto, pero si hago un `opendocument` no vuelva la información proveniente de la consulta `SELECT * FROM T_AUX`.

¿Cómo puedo abrir desde la macro el fichero y que cargue dicha información?